# display image instead of path in ModelForm in a fresh view in django

Tags: python, django, view, imagefield

I know the way to display image in Admin views for a model's list display and edit view.

But, I need the image to display in a different view I have created for end user - to be able to upload more/delete existing photos/images under his id.

These are the code changes I have made. It works perfect for Admin views; but not for my custom views.

**Model Definition:**

```
    class Photo(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    stars = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
#        return self.artist.last_name+','+self.artist.first_name
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width:100px;" />' % self.upload.url)

    def image_img(self):
        if self.upload:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width:100px;"/>' % self.upload.url)
        else:
            return '(Sin imagen)'
    image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
    image_img.allow_tags = True
```

**Views.py:**

```
class PhotosetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('upload', 'image_img')
        readonly_fields = ('image_img')
        exclude = ['artist', 'stars']

def photoset_update(request, pk, template_name='portfolios/photoset_form.html'):
    this_artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, pk=pk)
    PhotoInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(Artist, Photo, fields=('upload',))
    photoset = PhotoInlineFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=this_artist)
    if photoset.is_valid():
        photoset.save()
        return redirect('portfolios:index')
    return render(request, template_name, {'formset':photoset,})
```

**Form.html:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal artist_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="row">
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {% for photo in formset %}
         <div class="well">
            {{ photo }}
         </div>   
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**But, in the end I am getting the below error:**

```
from . import views
File "C:\Users\babya\OneDrive - Hewlett Packard Enterprise\PycharmProjects3x\M
odelsCompany\djangoproject\portfolios\views.py", line 96, in <module>
    class PhotosetForm(ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\babya\OneDrive - Hewlett Packard Enterprise\PycharmProjects3x\M
odelsCompany\djangoproject_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 2
62, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (image_img) specified for Ph
oto
```

Please help..!

Comment: you are calling a function but Django is looking for a modelfield (in your case it would be "upload"). I'm not sure what you did there it seems a bit outdated and I can't help you with it but I cn show you how I display my Images if you want.

Comment: yeah,I found it out later. I used the upload field from photo.intance to display image.

Comment: yeah the current way is the way I wanted to show you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the form view in template as below. Manually rendered fields rather then using built in methods and retrieved the existing url from model instance to display it and add the edit field also. The image_tag method from models.py didn't really appear useful in views other than admin views. I removed it from fields list tin ModelForm in views to prevent the above error. It will be easier that way in admin views rather than editing the admin templates.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal artist_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for photo in formset %}
            {{ photo.id }}
            <div class="col-sm-3 edit-thumbnail">
                <div class="edit-pic">
                    {% if photo.instance.upload %}
                        <a href="{{ photo.instance.upload.url }}" target="new">
                            <img class="edit-face" src="{{ photo.instance.upload.url }}" />
                        </a>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="img-placeholder">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
                            <p>Add Image</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% render_field photo.upload class+="form-control" placeholder="Photo" %}
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="del-checkbox glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn-checkbox btn btn-primary">
                        {% render_field photo.DELETE %}Delete
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %} 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Django UpdateView class based view(CBV). Then you can override the **get_context_object** attribute to name your file object. Then in the template you can call your object by what you named it, and display it in a HTML *img* tag. FYI: If you don't name it object name will simply just be "object"

When you are calling the form in the template using the formset

```
{{ form.file.label_tag }}
{{ form.file }}
{{ form.file.errors }}
```

You can just call the object name you set in get_context_object and use it as such. Here's an example of a form I did this on.

**Views.py-> UpdateView**

```
class FileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = SomeModel
    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = 'some-template.html'
    context_object_name = 'image'
```

**Forms.py**

```
{{ form.file.label_tag }}
#  Here is where you call the object url
<img src="{{ image.file.url }}" height="200"/><br/>
{{ form.file }}
{{ form.file.errors }}
```

This would be the way to do it, instead of hacking your way around it.